# Identifying duplicates with two criterias with MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm using MySQL Workbench to extract a list.

This is what my database looks like:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUphT.png)

I'm trying to identify the composer with the most duplicated tracks in this database.

This is the code I entered:

```sql
SELECT Name, Composer, Count(*) FROM Track

GROUP BY Name, Composer

HAVING Count(*)>1

ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

As a result of this query, I have the number of duplicates per tracks, alongside the composer. The thing is I have duplicates in composers. Therefore, my code gives me the track that is the most duplicated and its associated composer. This is not what I'm looking for. How can I have identify the composer with the most duplicated tracks in this database?

Here is a result of my query if it can help:
[query-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMpE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query as a subquery, and wrap another query around it. (This building of queries from subqueries is part of the *Structured* in *Structured Query Language*).

Something like this might work.

```sql
SELECT Composer, SUM(tracks) duplicate_tracks
  FROM (SELECT Name, Composer, Count(*) tracks 
               FROM Track
              GROUP BY Name, Composer
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) duptracks
 GROUP BY Composer
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

It uses your query as if it were a table (which it is, a virtual table) and runs a GROUP BY on it.  To use your query that way, it needs a name on the `COUNT(*)` item, so I gave it the name `tracks`. It also needs a name on the subquery. I used `duptracks` for that.

The outer query adds up all the duplicated tracks by composer with `SUM() ... GROUP BY Composer` then orders them presenting the composer with the most duplicated tracks first.

But notice that this works on the contents of your `Composer` columns as a whole.  It will use `John, Paul, Ringo, George` as if they were just one composer, and not count duplicates separately for each person.